# Load Contract in web3j

Tags: web3js, ethereumj, web3j

What is the equivalent of (in Web3Js)

```
token = web3.eth.contract(erc20abi).at(tokenAddress);
```

in Web3J

I have the erc20abi and the contract address, i want to perform transfer from one address to another.

Answer (score 1):

in Web3j we use :

```
YourSmartContract contract = YourSmartContract.load("0x<address>", web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
```

of course we don't provide Abi as argument since the YourSmartContract is a warper class for your contract in which web3j has already the ABI defined :

```
static final String BINARY = "606060405234610000575...…….."
```